# State transition - time taken.- SQL

Tags: sql, state, presto

I am trying to find the total time taken per state, given a sequence of value transitions. Here is an example:

Input:

| Time | State |
| --- | --- |
| 10:00:00 | A |
| 10:00:01 | A |
| 10:00:02 | B |
| 10:00:03 | B |
| 10:00:05 | A |
| 10:00:07 | B |
| 10:00:08 | A |
| 10:00:09 | B |
| 10:00:20 | A |
| 10:00:21 | B |

Output:

| state | time_taken_seconds |
| --- | --- |
| A | 6 |
| B | 15 |

I couldn't get the functionality working in SQL. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please tag the database you are using.

Comment: This is for Presto queries.

Comment: How difference is getting calculated? I see that state A started at 10:00:00 and ended at 10:00:20. This should be 20 secs right? What is the rationale behind 6 secs as your expected output?

Comment: @Arun It is the time taken at a specific state. If you see the input table, it is totally 6 seconds in state A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use analytical function lead() for referring time on the next row.

```
select state, sum(lap) from (
    select
        time,
        state, 
        lead(time) over(order by time) - time as lap 
    from tablenane
)
group by state
```

Comment: Can you comment as to why it is ordered by time in the window function?

Comment: lead(x) pick up x value from the next row in order by time